# cassandra installation on windows 10 , unable to connect to server

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

i have installed "datastax-ddc-64bit-3.9.0.msi" on windows 10, when i run Cassandra CQL Shell i have got this error.

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})

Comment: Could you verify if your firewall has open port 9042?

Answer (score 0):

What is the rpc_address configured? And connect CQL with that hostname/IP. E.g.

```
cqlsh <rpc_address> <native_transport_port>
```

Check the above values in your Cassandra.yaml file.